# regex pattern matching for http

Tags: c#, html, regex, href

i want to extract url from href of a webpage...for that i m using the regex pattern as
"(?(http:[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)"

to extract the href from html i used this pattern
 @"href=\""(?[^\""#]*?(?=[\""#]))(?(?#{2}[^#]*?#{2})*)(?#[^""]+)?"""

but the problem is...it do not extract urls from the href but urls like "www.seo-sem.com"..and in the result i only get.."www.seo"...after the hyphen it gets truncated...plz could u sugest a better regex pattern to extract url from href..will be thankful to u...

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML.  Find a simple library like HTMLAgilityPack and use that.

Comment: No one posted the link yet? :)

Comment: Even for basic URI matching the regular expression needed is *Ugly* (yes, capital U).

Comment: @rebus, well, it's not so much HTML parsing, actually. It doesn't try to do anything with the actual *structure* of the document. For simply grabbing anything that looks like `href='url'` regex may just be appropriate enough.

Comment: (http://|https://)?([\w.-]+)?([\w-]+\.[\w-]+) with `\2` and `\3` backrefs referencing subdomains and domain respectively would help probably, but by no means would it catch all possible domain names out there.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse your HTML. You can query it using Xpath, as it parses the HTML into a `XmlDocument` like object.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for reasons not to parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: i resolved the hyphen issue...edited regex..thanks anyways..u all rock..keep it up